# asdf python not picking up arrow library

Tags: python

So I have a basic Python class module where I am importing the arrow library.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import arrow

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
```

I have a test file that I am invoking with `pytest some_test_file.py` which imports `SomeClass` module. I get `E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arrow'`.

I did a `pip install arrow` and `asdf reshim python` and `asdf reshim python 3.7.2` but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using wrong python. Like you can see below it works:

```
pako@b00s:~$ pyenv shell 3.7.0
pako@b00s:~$ pip install arrow
Collecting arrow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/7f/0360628ba40bb93c10cd89cd289b6a8e9ea87b2db884b8edf32c80ee1c73/arrow-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from arrow) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->arrow) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: arrow
Successfully installed arrow-0.13.1
pako@b00s:~$ vim some_test_file.py
pako@b00s:~$ python some_test_file.py 
pako@b00s:~$ pip freeze | grep -i arrow
arrow==0.13.1
```